# Cómo sumar en una celda los datos de una columna de una matriz filtrada con UNIQUE()

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una duda que aparentemente puede ser muy fácil, pero no logro dar con la solución.

Quiero que en una celda x se muestra la sumatoria de la 3er. columna de una matriz filtrada con UNIQUE(). Para clarificar, pongo de ejemplo la fórmula:

```
 =suma(unique(a:c))
```

Esta fórmula devuelve la sumatoria de todas las columnas filtradas, de la A a la C. ¿cómo puedo obtener solamente la sumatoria de los datos de la columna C?

Comment: No lo he probado, pero ¿no funcionaría algo en plan `=suma(unique(C:C))`?

Comment: ¿podrías poner una planilla de ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede obtener con la funcion **Query**

=query(unique(a:c);"select sum(Col3)")

[Ayuda](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=es-419)